# 403 during posting data to cloudsearch

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

The following is the code:

```
import requests
url = 'document_url/documents/batch'
payload = "[{...}, {....}]"
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print('response code:', response.status_code)
print('response body:', response.json())
```

The following yields:

```
response code: 403  
response body: {'message': 'Request forbidden by administrative rules', '__type': 'CloudSearchException'}
```

The security rules are also opened up to all.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the discussion forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=148917

The document url should be:

> document_url/2013-01-01/documents/batch

response after posting to the above url:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "adds": 1,
  "deletes": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This totally due to using the Document End point with adding API version as below.

Since you are trying to insert data into Cloud Search you need to use Document End point of Cloud Search given to you by AWS.

It needs to be followed by the API version as below:

```
https://doc-xxxxx.zzzz.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/documents/batch
```

Same time be mindful to add content-type as well or you could end up getting `HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type` Error.

```
addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
```